# Nested bool and filter queries in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an index of resumes with some nested fields. I am running the following code to get the resumes which have Ruby in their skills, and computer in their education.

```
GET /resume/candidates/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "sections",
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                  "must": [
                    {"match": {"sections.skills": "Ruby"}}
                  ], 
                    "filter" : [
                    { "term" : {"sections.education": "computer"} }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The bool and filter queries give proper results when I run them separately. However when i combine them, they give no result. There is a resume in my index with skills ruby and computer under education.

Alternatively, for the moment I'm leaving the score part, and putting both under the same must conditions as follows:

```
GET /resume/candidates/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "sections",
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                  "must": [
                    {"match": {
                      "sections.skills": "Ruby"}},

                    {"match": {
                      "sections.education": "computer"}}

                  ]
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It still does not return any result, but it does return results if written separately. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Are you looking for a result that has BOTH or EITHER?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Need both

Comment: Change The Query Structure. Bool Query Consisting of Two Nested Queries.

Comment: @MohammadMazraeh I can't do that. That will affect the score if it's inside the bool query. It needs to be filtered away.

Comment: @MohammadMazraeh I tried that as well. Didn't work. Can you check the new code I put up?

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to have your mapping. By the way I've tried to create your scenario using this codes and the query works:

First define the mapping

```
PUT resume
{
  "mappings": {
    "candidates": {
      "properties": {
        "sections": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "skills": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "education": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then add two candidates to it:

```
PUT resume/candidates/1
{
  "sections": [
    {
      "skills": "Ruby",
      "education": "computer"
    },
    {
      "skills": "elastic",
      "education": "computer"
    }
  ]
}


PUT resume/candidates/2
{
  "sections": [
    {
      "skills": "kibana",
      "education": "computer"
    },
    {
      "skills": "elastic",
      "education": "computer"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is the query:

```
GET resume/candidates/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "sections",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "sections.education": {
                  "value": "computer"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "sections.skills": "Ruby"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And it only returns the first canidate:

```
{
  "took": 11,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.87546873,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "resume",
        "_type": "candidates",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.87546873,
        "_source": {
          "sections": [
            {
              "skills": "Ruby",
              "education": "computer"
            },
            {
              "skills": "elastic",
              "education": "computer"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```